# Units in HTML for iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, ios

What CSS [measurement unit](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp) should I use for the dimensions (widths, heights, margins, paddings, fonts, etc.) of an embedded HTML resource that should run both on iPhone and iPad?

Or should I use alternate CSS styles for iPhone/iPad instead?

I would like the content of this resource to look well on both devices, without having two create to versions of the same HTML.

Comment: probably `em`, though i'm not familiar with iP*d behavior.

Comment: http://line25.com/tutorials/design-and-code-a-cool-iphone-app-website-in-html5

Answer (score 1):

Status bar: 19 px

Navigation bar: 43 px

Content window: 369 px

Toolbar: 48 px

Safari toolbar is 44 pixels.

http://www.iphonecompatible.net/design-tips-tools/iphone-safari-screen-dimensions-layout/

Nice tool:
http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/screen.php

Comment: pixels are problematic since you have multiple resolutions for iphone screens. That means setting something to 19px in iphone 3 will display bigger than on the iphone 4. That is specially problematic since small buttons are hard to click. So I would use these guidelines, but I would convert them to inches or centimeters.

Answer (score 0):

The units are totally up to you. You can use whatever you are conversant with. I tend to use pixels because I find them most intuitive and easiest to measure on a computer screen. Also, during most webapp demos in Apple conferences, the unit used is pixels. It's pretty standard.

Checkout http://pxtoem.com to see conversions between units.

Cheers.